# Delete all records after 10 mins

Tags: php, mysql

Edit: Fixed

I'm writing a user counter with mysql and php, this will update all connected users in 10 mins into a table, and every 10 mins, it will delete all records from  that table.

My table is like:

**id** (int, auto increment) | **session** (varchar) | **time** (int)

But my query used to delete record is not correct, It doesnt work. Someone help me, plz!!!

```
<?php
 $session = session_id();
 $time = time();     
 $time_check = $time - 900;                
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "user"; 
 $tbl_name = "useronline";   

// Create connection
 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// Update session
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE session='$session'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);                   
$count = $result->num_rows;    
if ($count == "0") {
  $sql1 = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name(session, time)VALUES('$session', '$time')";
  $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
} else {
  $sql2 = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET time='$time' WHERE session = '$session'";
  $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
}

// Count session online
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
$count_user_online = $result3->num_rows;

// Delete session
$sql4 = 'DELETE FROM useronline WHERE time<$time_check';
$result4 = $conn->query($sql4);

// Total session 
 $sql5 = 'SELECT id FROM useronline ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';
 $result5 = $conn->query($sql5);
 $row = $result5->fetch_assoc();     
 $total = $row['id'];

 mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
```

output:

```
User online: <?php echo $count_user_online; ?><br />
Total  :  <?php echo $total; ?>
```

Comment: Please post desired output and output received with current logic?

Comment: cron job based upon time stamp?

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand you delete query, why are you doing a Not in ? Should'nt it be juste like this : `'DELETE FROM useronline WHERE time<$time_check';`
  ?

Comment: ty, I forgot even table is empty, ID always continue auto increment

Comment: Something important i forgot : in PHP you cant use variables in single quotes text. You should either replace them by double quotes or do this : `'Delete from useronline where time <'.$time_check;`

Comment: Did you try to do an echo of your query and then  copy paste your query into your mysql database? You can check the value of the time column  in your database and the $time_check var .

Comment: fixed, only need remove  $result4 = $conn->query($sql4);

Comment: humm, If you do this it will never delete the record right?